How to reach your destination?
A planar manifold bounded by the perimeter of your left foot intersects a parallel plane. Directly ahead of you, a point in the plane, is your destination. You have reached your destination when the manifold of your left foot intersects the point. Every step you take moves the manifold of your left foot a distance $s$  along a perfectly straight line that intersects the destination point, and your destination is a distance $ns$ away from you, where $n$ is a natural $\ge 2$.
The problem is that whenever you take a step forward, you take two steps backwards. You are not allowed to rotate any degree around your frontal, vertical and saggital axes.
What you are allowed to do is defined as the complement of what you are not allowed to do:

Move the manifold of your left foot along any direction parallel to the plane other than by taking a step $= s$.
Rotate along the aforementioned axes.
Change or move the plane in any way.
Change the shape/size of the manifold of your left foot in any way.
Change the premises of the puzzle.

So the question is: how can you reach your destination?

Are you sure this isn't [[tag:lateral-thinking]] instead of [[tag:logical-deduction]]? The former is for "ahah!" moments. The latter is for logical proofs.

This list of things I am allowed to do seems like it opens the puzzle up to a lot of loopholes. For instance: it seems that I am allowed to take a step without moving my left foot manifold, which trivializes things.

to what extent is the math talk necessary here? If I posed this as just walking forward with more everyday language, would the puzzle be materially different? Would the solution not work?

@bobble Perhaps given that view it is both, so I've edited the tags.

"it seems that I am allowed to take a step without moving my left foot manifold" You don't reach the destination until the left foot manifold intersects the destination, which is not already intersecting it. So, obviously, you cannot make them intersect without moving it. Furthermore, how do you reckon this? Stepping forward with your right foot would still take you two steps back each time, so how does it change things? Anyways, I've edited the question to clarify things. In the old version, I still tihnk you'd be wrong however.

You'd take a step forward with the manifold, leaving it in place for the two steps back.

@GoblinGuide Aha, I see, would have been a cool solution actually. I've edited this possibility out by specifying that you are always stepping forward by moving the left foot's manifold forward.

Isn't "intersects a parallel plane" an oxymoron?

@user110391 I'm confused how something could both be logical reasoning (which generally obeys given rules) and thinking outside the box/bending the rules, but if you think that's right then the tags are fine.

@bobble Because a puzzle does not consist of one step? Some steps may be lateral, others logical. The thing about this puzzle is that you have a whole universe of possibilities, and you are just supposed to intuitively move your focus to the right one. Once you have however, it is a matter of logic to check if it is indeed in-line with the puzzle's requirements.

@KateGregory Now that the answer has come, you can try to construct this puzzle in a non-mathematical, non-ambiguous way that only allows for the same solution(s). Then see if you think that formulation is simpler and better.

I think the question shows research effort and is useful to me, thanks for posting it!

I think I'll just

 erect a line perpendicular to the plane so that it goes through my foot.

Next, I will

 mirror myself over to the other side of that line

and start walking. (Either forwards or backwards.)

This should meet all the requirements, because I was forbidden from doing these things:

Move the manifold of your left foot along any direction parallel to the plane other than by taking a step =

Didn't move at all

Rotate along the aforementioned axes.

Didn't rotate (except effectively)

Change or move the plane in any way.

Didn't do that either

Change the shape/size of the manifold of your left foot in any way.


 This is why I needed to mirror over a line specifically; mirroring over a point or over a plane would have changed my left foot's shape to its mirror image (the right foot).

 Mirroring over a line is equivalent to mirroring over two intersecting planes, so the result is the mirror image of the mirror image, which is the original shape.


More importantly, the resulting foot has its front and back reversed, so now "forwards" is away from the destination, and walking "one step forward and two steps back" (or just walking backwards in case I need to save some time) will bring me to the destination.

Change the premises of the puzzle.

Don't think I did any of that either, seeing how this is a lateral-thinkinggeometry puzzle, and those were the two tools I used.

You can reach your destination by

simultaneously taking n steps forward (after which you will take 2n steps backwards).


"Two steps taken simultaneously" is just one doubly-large step taken. It cannot be two steps, because for something to be a step, the foot must lift from and land on the ground. "Two steps taken simultaneously" only involves one lifting and one landing, and is thus only one step, but with double the length. This is illegal in the puzzle, since one can only move the manifold in steps of size $s$. And whenever one has moved it forward a step, one moves it backwards two steps.

@user110391 I must have missed the part about lifting and landing in the definition of a step.

Maybe Cambridge can help you? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/step  And if that is not satisfactory, what even is a step if not something with some kind of (abstract) start and end? How is a step defined if its start and end is not defined? And if its end is defined, then there is some moment where the requirement of stepping two steps backwards would come into effect. That moment is after one has traversed a distance of $s$. So even if you abstract away from human walking, the term "step" contains the meaning necessary to refute your attempt at a solution.

I used the definition given by "Every step you take moves the manifold of your left foot a distance s
along a perfectly straight line that intersects the destination point." I thought the whole point was to rely on an abstract mathematical formulation as opposed to more everyday language.

That's not a definition of "step", but a description of the movement you can make; a description that contains in it that this movement is a step; if there was no step-like nature to the movement, then "step" would not feauture in the description. "I thought the whole point was to rely on an abstract mathematical formulation as opposed to more everyday language." If the meanings of the everday language words were to be ignored, then I wouldn't have used them. You have to ask yourself why I wrote "step" in the first place when alternatives would far better suit your interpretation.
